# Inputing numbers unless the number 0 is inputed. Then checking if those, entered numbers, are dividable with number n (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers

As you can see from title I am trying to input numbers unless I enter number 0. The problem that I have is that I am entering numbers in for loop and with array. The actual problem with that is that I am entering the numbers unless the "i" reaches the number 100 (as you can see from the code).
Even if I enter the number 0, it doesnt do nothing.
I am beginner at C++, so if you are not understanding the code or I am going in the completely wrong way with this, please help me.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n; 
    int number[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (number[i] != 0)
        cin >> number[i];
    }

    cout << "Enter number n: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (number[i] % n == 0)
        cout << number[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the just entering numbers, like I said in the beggining.
P.S:I can use whatever I want (vectors,functions...)

Comment: @Scheff "...leave the input value unitialized" this was true for long time, but not anymore since C++11.

Comment: Btw. you should check `number[i]` for 0 in your output loop as well. Otherwise, it will process all 100 `number` elements - even the one after the 0 which you use as terminator.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ah - I just looked into [operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) and I see, you're correct. (I always ignored the part with _(since C++11)_) My fault. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff no worries, actually I don't understand that change, because if input failed there is no use for that `0`. It can be misinterpreted as encouraging not to check the state of the stream after taking input, but checking for `0` instead. Perhaps there was just too much code wich got it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major problem is the check you have:

```
if (number[i] != 0)
```

It's a major problem because it's done *before* you initialize anything in `number[i]`, when its value is *indeterminate*. And using indeterminate values lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your program.

If you want to skip zeroes in the input, you need to read into a temporary variable, and check if *that* value is zero or not.

You also need to keep track of the number of values you have input in a different way, since zeroes should not be counted.

Perhaps something like this:

```
size_t count = 100;

// Loop while we have still have numbers to input
while (count > 0)
{
    int temp;

    // Read a number from the user
    std::cin >> temp;

    // If it's not zero, then add it to the array, else just ignore it
    if (temp != 0)
    {
        // 100 - count will result in the index where the number is added to the array
        input[100 - count] = temp;

        // One less number to read
        --count;
    }
}
```

---

There are of course better solutions than the one shown above, but it should hopefully be clearer, as well as don't use anything you might not have been taught yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I interpret your code correctly, but you have the logic reversed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (number[i] != 0)
    cin >> number[i];
}
```

Here you check for `0` before you read user input. Instead you should first read input and only then check if it was `0` (and you should never try to access something before it is initialized, as is the case for your `number` array).

For dynamically sized arrays you can use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
int number;
while ( std::cin >> number && number != 0) {
    numbers.push_back(number);
}
```

This will also stop when the user entered something that cannot be read as `int` and after that loop `numbers.size()` tells you how many numbers have been entered.